# How to save a custom sort order between products?

Tags: php, mysql

I was not able to find a proper answer to what I am looking for! Maybe I am not asking the right questions.

That being said, I want to add the ability to custom sort (rearrange) products from the CMS. When I am in the CMS in the products list page, I want to be able to push UP and DOWN or drag and drop each product between another. e.g.:

[image]

I have a table filled with thousands of products and I want to custom sort it.

So my query would look something like this

```
SELECT id,product_name,price FROM products ORDER BY sort_order DESC;
```

First I would have to add the column `sort_order` to the table. I was thinking initially of filling it with exactly the same value of the row `id`, but instead of it being an int(11) I would use a decimal value. so if I want to move product `123123227` between `123123225` and `123123226` I would calculate the new sort_order like so:

```
$product_A_pos = 123123225.0;
$product_B_pos = 123123226.0;
$product_C_pos = 123123227.0;
$new_product_C_pos = ($product_A_pos + $product_B_pos)/2;
// I round it so it wouldn't be too big for the mysql column
$new_product_C_pos = round($new_product_C_pos, 5);
```

That is all great until I did a test to see what is that max number of products you can add between `123123225` and `123123226` and then between `the new inserted product` and `123123226` and found out that it is only 16 till you can insert no more between them.

using this test:

```
$old_product_C_sort_order = 0;
$product_A_sort_order = 123123225.0;
$product_B_sort_order = 123123226.0;
$product_C_sort_order = 123123227.0;
$new_product_C_sort_order = ($product_A_sort_order + $product_B_sort_order)/2;
$index = 0;
$epsilon = 0.00001;

while ($new_product_C_sort_order < $product_B_sort_order && $new_product_C_sort_order != $product_B_sort_order && !(abs($old_product_C_sort_order-$new_product_C_sort_order) < $epsilon)){
    $index++;
    $old_product_C_sort_order = $new_product_C_sort_order;
    $new_product_C_sort_order = ($new_product_C_sort_order + $product_B_sort_order)/2;
    $new_product_C_sort_order = round($new_product_C_sort_order, 10);
}
echo 'count: '.$index;
```

> count: 16

Or should I be doing this on the MySQL level with something like this:

```
START TRANSACTION;

UPDATE products SET sort_order = sort_order + 1 WHERE sort_order >= 123123226 order by sort_order;

DELETE FROM products where id = 123123227;
INSERT INTO products (id,product_name,price) VALUES (123123227, 'C', 123123226);

COMMIT;
```

making sure that the sort_order is int(11). or is this a bad idea?

Is there a better solution to deal with this issue? should I be using a completely different way to approach it? and how?

Comment: what is the data type that you have used for sort_order?

Comment: @DhavalChheda I still haven't decided yet

Comment: Then how do u know it takes only 16 values between 2 integers?

Comment: @DhavalChheda the limitation is in the way I am producing the sort_order value (in the test I made)

Comment: I think you should look to implement something like a linked list e.g:- you save 2 additional columns which will have previous id and next id and then whenever you want to insert any row then you update these 2 columns of all 3 rows (the actual row , the row above it, the row after it ) .. I will recommend you try to work out a logic around this..

Comment: @DhavalChheda actually it would be 5 rows that needs to get updated (the actual row , the row above it, the row after it , OLD row above it, OLD row after it). not sure if this is the best solution.